# Force Angular child component to render completely

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have the following [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecf1aq?file=src/app/child2/child2.component.ts).

When I am updating the child data source it's not rendering completely, the below method is not being called,

```
 updatedSelectedText() {
    this.SelectedData = "";
    console.log(this.data);
    this.data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.Selected) this.SelectedData += el.Text;
    });
  }
```

I can make it call on

```
ngDoCheck() {
    // this.updatedSelectedText();
  }
```

But in real project, I have much complex logic written, that I do not want to call on *ngDoCheck* method.

Is there any way to force the child component to render completely

I tried **`ChangeDetectionStrategy`** but this is not working.

Comment: could you write what you want? what button should be clicked and what should be updated

Comment: in stackblitz when you click on change then it should update the text below change button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the "child2" to onEmitEvent and call to the function updatedSelectedText()?

That's, you change your app.component.html

```
<!--see that use a template reference variable "#child2", and pass as
    argument to update function -->
<app-child1 (onEmit)="update($event,child2)" [data]="jsondata"></app-child1>
<app-child2 #child2 [data]="jsondata.AdDimensionsMaster"></app-child2>
```

In update function of app.component.ts just call the function

```
//get the "child2" as "any"
update(event: any,child2:any) {
    this.jsondata.AdDimensionsMaster[event].Selected = true;
    this.jsondata.isactive = true;
    child2.updatedSelectedText() //<--call the function
}
```

Comment: function is not calling

Comment: see your forked stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issagg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

1. In Child2Component the `updatedSelectedText` method is called in `ngOnInit` which is called only once - when component is initialized. There is two ways to solve it:

   - by using a setter/getter for `@Input()`
   - by using a `NgOnChanges` lifecycle hook

NOTE: Both setter and `ngOnChanges` are called before `ngOnInit` so you can avoid this hook

2. In AppComponent the `update` method should update the `jsondata` object instead change single property

Take a look on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwrwub)

Comment: This is cool, one question , on appcomponent.ts, is it possible without map, as i know the index

Comment: Also when I do ngDoCheck, i don't need to do get/set, so how this will impact the performance

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam Yes, it's possible by coping an array to local variable and then you can easily change single item based on index and setting local array to the object. Example: https://pastebin.com/XYCyuJJu

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam You can use `ngDoCheck`, but you mentioned in question that you do not want to use that hook in real project. After all `ngOnChanges` is better place to doing it than `ngDoCheck`